# Integrating "Dante" YSIWYG Medium-Style Editor into a Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wysihtml5

I'm attempting to integrate the "Dante" WYSIWYG text editor into my Rails project. I have it installed and displaying on the screen. See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/73hKl.png

However, in my Rails app I have users that have_many stories. I'd like to use this editor to allow users to create these stories. I need to wire the editor and the form together basically, but I have no idea how to go about doing that, as I've never done something like this before. Would anyone mind giving me some tips please?

Documentation for editor is here: https://github.com/michelson/Dante

Current page:

```
<%= simple_form_for @story do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :subtitle %>
  <%= f.input :content, :id => "editor" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
<hr>
<div id="editor">
<h1 id="dante-editor">Click Me Once. Your Title Goes Here.</h1>

<h2>Tell us about your favorite backpacking adventure. This might also be a great place to add a picture.</h2>

<p>Simply replace and highlight any text here to add text. Press "Enter" to add more text or add images. Click on the image to add a caption. It's easy once you get the hang of it, just play around with it for a minute.</p>
</div>
<hr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  editor = new Dante.Editor(
    {
      el: "#editor",
      upload_url: "/images.json", //it expect an url string in response like /your/server/image.jpg or http://app.com/images/image.jpg
      store_url: "/save" //post to save

    }
  );
  editor.start()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for @story do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :subtitle %>
<%= f.input :content, :id => "editor" %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Put the div inside of your form and make it hidden field
into like this

```
<%= simple_form_for @story do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :title %>
<%= f.hidden_field :subtitle %>
<%= f.hidden_field :content, html: { id: "content"} %> // Use 'id' in your content field and match it in your editor div. Use data field data-field-id="content"

<div id="#editor" data-field-id="content">
   <%= @story.cotent.try (:html_safe) %> 
   // @story is your instance variable and .content is db column from      story  
</div> 
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

then use jquery to bind the editor content in content field which is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editor").bind("input properchange", function(){
    $("#story_" + $(this).attr("data-field-id")).val($(this).html())
    });
});
```

NOTE: It only save the text content not the image